# finding all the pairs in an array whose product is less than equal to a constant k

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

```
int fun(int A[], int n, int k) {
  int count = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int j = n - 1;
  
  // Traverse the array
  while (i < j) {
    if (A[i] * A[j] <= k) {
      count += (j - i);
      i++;
    }
    else {
      j--;
    }
  } 
  return count; 
}
```

I have used the following logic to solve the question :

1. I have sorted the array.
2. I have used the two-pointer method which I mentioned above to find the number of pairs whose product is less than or equal to k.
   the time complexity of the procedure turned out to be O(N log N) please suggest any optimizations to my procedure so that i get an O(n) solution to this problem. can I solve this problem without sorting?

Comment: Generalizing the input to real numbers, I'm pretty sure this requires Ω(n log n) operations on the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_RAM by reduction from element distinctness.

Comment: There are o(n log n) integer sorting algorithms, so basically it depends on your machine model.

Comment: Does `A` have a limited range?

Comment: This seems to be a programming-language-specific question: please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: @Damien no the input is not having a limited range

Comment: Is the `count` variable the quantity of pairs?  If so, should it be incremented rather than assigning `(j - i)`?

Comment: You don't print the pairs or store the pairs that meet the criteria.

Comment: This is possible as long as there are less than about `O(N)` pairs.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the 2SUM problem (and benefits a bit from the 3SUM problem solutions). A full `O(N)` solution doesn't exist because it is possible that there are as many as `O(N)` pairs. However, if the number of pairs is `O(N)` then we can solve it in `O(N)`.

Consider `a + b = k`, we can rewrite this as `a - k = b`. For each `a` we can check if `b` exists by first storing all numbers in a set with a `O(1)` lookup. Then for each `a` we calculate `b` and we can verify if b exists or not in `O(1)`, do that `N` times and we have `O(N)`.

What about if `a * b <= k`, now we use `k / b <= b`. This seems trickery, but it's actually way easier. It leads us to a `O(N + Z)` output sensitive algorithm. `Z` is the number of valid pairs. `Z` can be as high as `O(N^2)`.

Let's consider an example. Let's say the numbers range from `10 to 1000`, and `k` is `10000`. `a * b <= k`. Using the rewritten formulas we get `10000 / b =< 10000/10 =< 1000 <= 10 <= b` and `10000 / 1000 <= 10 <= b`. So any value less than `1000` is a potentially valid solution (since is 10 less than 1000 as well). This is because we can now efficiently bound the values by filtering out for all values above 70. Let's say there are `M` values. Then we only have to sort on those `M` values, meaning it only costs `O(M log M)` to sort. However, `O(M log M)` is probably less than `O(Z)` in practice so I used `O(Z)` instead. Though I suppose we could technically call it `O(N + M log M + Z)`.
This gives us our output sensitive approach that can be considered O(`N`) if `Z` is well below N.

1. Find the min value of the array, call it `M`. `O(N)`. Calculate `b`, the max value of possible solution, from this.
2. Get list of find all values less than or equal to `M`. Sort the list. `O(M log M)` (`M` being the list of this list)
3. Loop over the list finding valid solutions. Basically work from max to min (b) and min to max (a) to bound the solution. Stop the inner loop if `a * b > k` so we run at `O(Z)` instead of `O(M^2)`. `O(Z)`

Python solution (as not sure what you need, but should help even if you need to convert the code):

```
# Step 1. Find b, O(N)
h = 10000.0 # Avoid integer division
values = [10, 100, 250, 300, 800, 10000]
m = min(values)
b = h / m

# Step 2. Bound, O(N)
bounded = []
for x in values:
  if x <= b:
    bounded.push(x)

# Step 3. List solutions, O(Z)
sorted_bounded = bounded.sorted()
reverse_bounded = bounded.sorted(reverse=true)
solutions = []
for i in range(len(reverse_bounded)):
  b = reverse_bounded[i]
  for j in range(len(sorted_bounded))
    a = sorted_bounded[j]
    if a * b <= k:
      solutions.push([a,b])
    else:
      break
```

One of those sorts can probably be removed in languages that are more friendly to using points from both directions of an array.

We can run this in O(N + M log M) if we only need to find the total number of solutions. Since we can do a binary search on the sorted `M` list to find index of the highest value that meets the requirement.

I used positive * positive in this example. If you have negative numbers, just handle `positive * positive`, `negative * negative`, and `negative * negative` as separate lists in terms of possible values for `a` and `b` it's `O(N)` to split the array into positive and negative numbers. More complex, but certainly doable, just didn't want to go there in this example.

Edit 1: Just noticed this was product instead of addition. Still works, but need to change `+` to `*` and `-` to `/` and update the example.

Edit 2: Fixed.

Edit 3: This was posted before language was added. Not familiar with C++.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, use the brute force method:

```
int quantity = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  const int multiplier = A[i];
  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
  {
    const int multiplicand = A[j];
    const int product = multiplier * multiplicand;
    if (product <= k)
    {
      std::cout << multiplier
                << " * "
                << multiplicand
                << " --> "
                << product
                << "\n";
      ++quantity;
    }
  }
}
```

You may want to measure the performance of the above code with an implementation that sorts the array first and removes duplicates, then does the multiplication and testing.

Sorting the array may take up time that could be used calculating the quantities.
For more efficiency, you may want to try loop unrolling; however the loop is quite simple and should execute quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can bring it down to O(N) using a hash table, but there will still be a dependence on k, so the final complexity will be O(Nk).

C++ implementation with a small example below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

int GetCount(const std::vector<int>& src, int k) {
    
    int count = 0;
    for(int bound = 1; bound <= k; ++bound) {
        std::unordered_set<int> seen{};
        for(auto& value:src) {
            if(bound%value != 0) // Guard against integer division effects.
                continue;
            int compliment = bound / value ; 
            auto pos = seen.find(compliment);
            if(pos != seen.end()) {
                std::cout << "Value: " << value << ", Compliment: " << compliment << " , Bound: " << bound << std::endl;
                count++;
            }
            seen.insert(value);
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> small_test = {1, 2, 2, 3};
    int small_test_k = 4; 
    // 4 pairs smaller than 4, (2*1, 2*1, 3*1, 2*2)
    int count = GetCount(small_test, small_test_k);
    std::cout << count << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```